# Android Studio - Update Excel DataBase with Apache POI through WiFi

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm looking for a way to update an Excel database with Apache POI through WiFi.

All the examples I found declare the file as being located on the PC hard drive, like this:

```
 File myFile = new File("C://temp/Example.xlsx");
```

How can I proceed considering that my file will be on the Network, and should be accessed by the device through WiFi?

Comment: Download the file, then open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is just checkout wifiP2P android class that allow us to connect to the peer of same network and also transfer the data...

here is the link :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p

here is the demo example of connecting, searching, transferring the data

check it out ....

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install software in order to do that. I think samba is a good option to go on.

Once u got samba installed you can get the file via:

smb://IPDeviceWho'sSharingTheFolder/Example.xlsx (considering it is on the main folder)

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Check out this for browsing so you can verify the visibility of the shared folder https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop